# How to set a custom position for Atlas pages in QGIS 2.18.14

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I want to set a position for each page/feature in the Atlas.

For scale and rotation I resolved here: [Set a custom maps rotations for specific pages in the print composer in QGIS](http://Set%20a%20custom%20maps%20rotations%20for%20specific%20pages%20in%20the%20print%20composer%20in%20QGIS2.14.3)

But now, I can´t find any option for positioning the content of a map/maps.

Edited to give more details...

This screenshot (1) shows a page of the Atlas using Data defined override on the Main properties, Scale and Map Rotation. It uses that two fields of the table from the coverage layer; scale and rotation.

[image]

The second screenshot shows what I need to do. Move the content to a better position... see (2).

[image]

Is there a way to control like I did with scale and rotation?

Comment: could you generate a set of polygons that represent your pages and use that as the Atlas coverage

Comment: Do u mean u want something different from the usual behaviour of QGIS Atlas (meaning the "current" feature of the atlas is controlling the center and extent of the map) ?

Comment: Yes, that´s it @snaileater. I want to change the alignment of the feature, to move around to another best position.

Comment: @IanTurton, I already have a coverage layer. I added more info to my original post.

Comment: Why don't u let the atlas generation compute the scale automatically ? If your problem is the lack of space on the right side of the composer (in your example) the usual behaviour of QGIS's atlas solves it by using a margin (given in pourcentage).